# Query (Inbox and Outbox, etc) for Private Messaging System - PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, messaging

I'm writing a private messaging system for a website. A user can communicate with one of more other users (including himself / herself). I have three tables

```
- users
- conversation_list
- conversation_messages
```

for my database as shown below.

The `users` table holds all users

The `conversation_messages` table holds the messages written, each message has a conversation_id

The `conversation_list` holds the list of participants in each conversation

Each conversation is of course, identified by the unique `conversation_id`

Now, I wish to query the following from the tables:

```
- getInboxMessages <-- Difficult
    Get all new messages directed to a user. 
    Replies to a message should be grouped as a conversation 
    and the latest reply previewed
- getOutboxMessages
    Get all messages sent by the user. 
    Replies to messages should be grouped as a conversation 
    and only the latest reply previewed
- getConversation
    Each message with all replies
- isUnreadMessage
    Check if a message has been read or not
- getNumberOfUnreadMessages
    Get the number of unread messages
```

What I have done so far is shown below.

`getOutboxMessages`, `getConversation`, `isUnreadMessage` and `getNumberOfUnreadMessages` do work, although the queries may not be optimal! I have real trouble getting the `getInboxMessages`.

I can only get the first thread of a conversation in the inbox. Any other threads (replies) do not aplear as new messages, but rather as sent messages (outbox). 
However, any reply to the message (part of a conversation) does not appear as a new message!

An ideas? Any support in getting the right query for getInboxMessages
as well as optimizing the queries is heartily welcome!

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `conversation_list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `conversation_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `added_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_lastPost` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_lastView` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `conversation_messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conversation_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `date_created` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) default NULL,
  `usersalt` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `userid` varchar(32) default NULL,
  `userlevel` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `regdate` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

QUERIES

```
getInboxMessages
================
SELECT *
FROM conversation_messages AS m
JOIN
    (SELECT mx.conversation_id,
     MAX(mx.date_created) AS MaxTime
    FROM conversation_messages AS mx
    GROUP BY mx.conversation_id) AS mx ON m.conversation_id = mx.conversation_id
    AND m.date_created = mx.MaxTime
JOIN
    (SELECT mu.conversation_id
     FROM conversation_list AS mu
     WHERE mu.user_id = :subuser
     GROUP BY mu.conversation_id) AS mux ON m.conversation_id = mux.conversation_id
JOIN conversation_list AS mu ON m.conversation_id = mu.conversation_id
GROUP BY mu.conversation_id
ORDER BY m.date_created DESC

getOuboxMessages
================
SELECT *
FROM conversation_messages AS m

JOIN
    (SELECT mx.conversation_id,
     MAX(mx.date_created) AS MaxTime
     FROM conversation_messages AS mx
     GROUP BY mx.conversation_id) AS mx ON m.conversation_id = mx.conversation_id
AND m.date_created = mx.MaxTime

JOIN
    (SELECT mu.conversation_id, mu.user_id
     FROM conversation_list AS mu
     WHERE mu.added_by = :subuser
     GROUP BY mu.conversation_id) AS mux ON m.conversation_id = mux.conversation_id

JOIN conversation_list AS mu ON m.conversation_id = mu.conversation_id

ORDER BY m.date_created DESC

isUnreadMessage
===============
SELECT * FROM conversation_list WHERE date_created >= date_lastView AND conversation_id = :messageid AND user_id = :subuser

getConversation
===============
SELECT conversation_id, message, sender, date_created 
FROM conversation_messages 
WHERE conversation_id = :submessage_id 
ORDER BY date_created DESC

getNumberOfUnreadMessages
=========================
SELECT l.conversation_id, count(*)
FROM   conversation_list l
JOIN   conversation_messages m ON m.conversation_id = l.conversation_id AND m.date_created >= l.date_lastview
WHERE  l.user_id = :subuser
GROUP BY l.conversation_id
```

Comment: Is there someone to give me a helping mind??